# parameter for navigation service (INavigationService)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, infragistics

I create a project with infragistic which generates the view and views models folders, what I want to do now is create a binding context to the view model as it is normally done, but this view model has INavigationService parameters and I don't know how to configure it. Those parameters, if someone helps me, I would really appreciate it, I attach images so that they understand me more.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehmeQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAsWT.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the mainPage background code you can use following code.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();


            this.BindingContext= new PersonsViewModel(Navigation); 


        }
}
```

This `Navigation` comes from  `NavigableElement` you can use `Navigation` directly in `ContentPage`.

`NavigableElement` is under the Xamarin.Forms namespace like following code.
[image]

============Prism==============

If you use Prism. you should registe it the `App.xaml.cs`.

```
public partial class App
    {
        /* 
         * The Xamarin Forms XAML Previewer in Visual Studio uses System.Activator.CreateInstance.
         * This imposes a limitation in which the App class must have a default constructor. 
         * App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) cannot be handled by the Activator.
         */
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

In your MainPage.xaml.cs you do not need other binding code.

Here is a demo about it.

https://github.com/manacespereira/xamarin-prism-navigation

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: hi, i have the same code in my file app.xml.cs, helpme please.

Comment: @JhonaJM If you do not add the `this.BindingContext= new PersonsViewModel()` in the `MainPage.xaml.cs`, if you can running normally?

Comment: yes, running normally,but i need use bindingcontext

Comment: Because Prism use dependency injection to decoupling, if you used `this.BindingContext= new PersonsViewModel()`, this operation will increase coupling, why you want to use this way?

Comment: What happens is that I want to fill a collection view following the following structure:
class in a model-> in the view model instantiate the class  and create an observablecollection like in the first photo, after that I would pass it with a bindingcontext to the xaml file

Comment: if you know a better way ,please help me